# Mapping address to multidimensional uint

Tags: solidity, arrays, mapping

I'm trying to create an array contains addresses which belongs to particular transaction ID.

Array structure:

```
transactions[0x12345][0] = 123456
transactions[0x12345][1] = 789101
transactions[0x12345][2] = 865436
```

Expected output when calling getAccountTransactions():

```
[0] = 123456
[1] = 789101
[2] = 865436
```

Code:

```
mapping (address => mapping(uint => uint)) public transactions;

function getAccountTransactions() public returns (uint[] tx) {

    return transactions[msg.sender];

}
```

Compiler returns error:

> TypeError: Return argument type mapping(uint256 => uint256) is not
>   implicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return
>   variable) uint256[] memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with your code is that you are trying to return a `uint[]` which is an `array`, however you defined your variable as a mapping of mappings, and `mapping` and `array` are different types.

You *could* get your code to compile like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract test {

    mapping (address => uint[]) public transactions;

    constructor() public {
        transactions[msg.sender].push(123456);
        transactions[msg.sender].push(789101);
        transactions[msg.sender].push(865436);
    }

    function getTransactions() public view returns (uint[]) {

        return transactions[msg.sender];

    }
}
```

However in general, I would not recommend a single function which returns all the values. While this may be useable in a web front-end, it will not scale as a normal contract function, since eventually you will reach a number of objects in the array where the gas cost to return them all will be too large for the evm.

Instead, I suggest you break it into two functions:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract test {

    mapping (address => uint[]) public transactions;

    constructor() public {
        transactions[msg.sender].push(123456);
        transactions[msg.sender].push(789101);
        transactions[msg.sender].push(865436);
    }

    function getTransactionsLength() public view returns (uint) {

        return transactions[msg.sender].length;

    }

    function getTransactionsValue(uint index) public view returns (uint) {

        return transactions[msg.sender][index];

    }
}
```

One is `getTransactionsLength()`, and the other is `getTransactionsValue()`. Both of these functions return just a single uint, which means you will have predictable output size and gas costs, which means it can be used in other parts of your contract.

Furthermore, you will also create better user experiences by controlling the number of values you are showing. If you need to show all the values, you could first get the `length`, and then loop the value call from `0 to length-1`.

But even better, you may only want to show the last 10 transactions in the UI, where then you can loop from `length-1 to length-11`. These may seem like complexities at first, but in reality will be simplifications to your dApp is it grows; things you will really come to appreciate from immutable programs :)

Comment: I cannot vote but thank you very much for the quick answer. Your example bring me some new ideas that I'm going to implement to my contract :)

Comment: No problem. If this answers your question, should be able to mark the answer as correct, which will the forum know that the problem is resolved! Good luck :)

Comment: Sure, message marked :)